Inconsistent vertical space above and below theorems with thmtools
I have some trouble with inconsistent spacing regarding my own theorem environment (see picture below)

The vertical spaces above and below theorems are not the same, as well as the spaces inside of the box.
Furthermore, there is more space around the proof environment than there is with no text.
I would like to be x1=x2=y1=y2, preferably everything to be around the same as the current x2 and to let z1=z2. Here is the code of my example:
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, german, xcolor=dvipsnames]{report}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools,thmtools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{cmbright}

\definecolor{theocolor}{RGB}{237, 138, 130}
\declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,%
notefont=\normalfont\bfseries,%
notebraces={}{},%
headpunct=,%
bodyfont=\normalfont,%  
headformat=\NAME~\NUMBER:\NOTE\newline,%
mdframed={
backgroundcolor=theocolor!20,
leftline=true,        
linewidth=4pt,        
linecolor=theocolor,            
topline=false,       
bottomline=false,     
rightline=false,      
skipabove = 12pt,     
skipbelow = 12pt,
innertopmargin=6pt,
innerbottommargin=6pt,
}
]{theoremstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=theoremstyle, numberwithin=chapter, name=Satz]{theorem}

\begin{document}

Dies ist ein Test, um den Abstand herauszufinden (hoffentlich).
\begin{theorem}
    Der Mittelwertsatz macht dies und das.
\end{theorem}
Dies ist ein Test, um den Abstand herauszufinden (hoffentlich).
\begin{theorem}  
    Der Mittelwertsatz macht dies und das.
\end{theorem}
%\vspace{-8pt}
\begin{proof}
    Das ist ein Beweis.
\end{proof}
\begin{theorem}
    Der Mittelwertsatz macht dies und das.
\end{theorem}
Dies ist ein Test, um den Abstand herauszufinden (hoffentlich).
\begin{proof}
    Das ist ein Beweis.
\end{proof}
\noindent Dies ist ein Test, um den Abstand herauszufinden (hoffentlich).

\end{document}

Do you have any ideas?

The proof spacing issue is a duplicate of Additional space around `proof` using `parskip`. For the box spacing, I would use tcolorbox instead of mdframed. Here is an option using the keytheorems package which, disclaimer, I wrote.
Your code had several redundancies that I removed.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{keytheorems}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{cmbright}

\definecolor{theocolor}{RGB}{237, 138, 130}
\newkeytheoremstyle{theoremstyle}
  {
    headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
    notefont=\normalfont\bfseries,
    notebraces={}{},
    headpunct={},
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
    break,
    headformat=\NAME~\NUMBER:\NOTE,
    tcolorbox-no-titlebar={
      sharp corners,
      colback=theocolor!20,
      boxrule=0pt,
      leftrule=4pt,       
      colframe=theocolor,
      left=8pt,
      right=8pt,
      }
  }
\newkeytheorem{theorem}[
  style=theoremstyle,
  numberwithin=chapter,
  name=Satz,
  ]

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep\z@skip % <---- changed here
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Dies ist ein Test, um den Abstand herauszufinden (hoffentlich).
\begin{theorem}[A note]
    Der Mittelwertsatz macht dies und das.
\end{theorem}
Dies ist ein Test, um den Abstand herauszufinden (hoffentlich).
\begin{theorem}  
    Der Mittelwertsatz macht dies und das.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
    Das ist ein Beweis.
\end{proof}
\begin{theorem}
    Der Mittelwertsatz macht dies und das.
\end{theorem}
Dies ist ein Test, um den Abstand herauszufinden (hoffentlich).
\begin{proof}
    Das ist ein Beweis.
\end{proof}
Dies ist ein Test, um den Abstand herauszufinden (hoffentlich).

\end{document}



Looks beautiful, thanks alot!!! :=)

If you don't mind sparing me another minute:
I have decided to switch to the scrreprt class with parkskip=half and made some new key theorems with the default style, like this:
\newkeytheorem{example}[   sibling=theorem,   name=Example, ]
Now I have the same problem again:
The space above and under the new key theorems is greater than above and under proofs for example. I tried to find default style in the .sty files for theorems so I could renew it, like you did with the proof environment but I couldn`t find it unfortunately.

Maybe another question should be posted. You can point to this solution and explain the new problem.

@NoahP See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729515/208544 but as projetmbc said, it's better to ask a new question than ask followup questions in the comments
